# rails sql match

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, where-clause

```
customer = Feedback.includes(:user).where("('created_at' >= ? and 
'created_at' < ? and how_did_you_hear = ? and 
users.user_type = ? )",date_start,date_end,value,"customer").count
```

This code match with all Feedbacks not only Feedback.user.user_type = "customer"

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could work:

```
customer = Feedback.includes(:user).where("feedbacks.created_at >= ? AND feedbacks.created_at < ? AND how_did_you_hear = ? AND users.user_type = 'customer'", date_start, date_end, value).count
```